# Printing a variable amount of checkboxradio depending on an array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'll introduce the problem with an image :

[image: checkboxradio variable amount]
These are checkboxradio from jquery, and what I'm trying to do is
print these checkbox but not always the same way, because the content in the checkbox will differ every time (because depending on what a user previously entered in an array)

For exemple, the suggestion 1 is of length 3 on the image, but could have a different length another time, up to a length of 10.
As well as the total number of row, which could be 1 or 2 or ... Up to 10.

I tried to code something, but it doesn't work, mostly because it's kind of disgusting and probably is a wrong way of doing it.

```
<?php 
/*
$words is a 2 dimensional array, which contains :
  row -> specific type (ex : Metal's type / Water's name...)
  column -> each words of a type (ex : Iron / Copper / Barium...)
*/
$i = 1; //Iterator through lignes
$j = 0; //Iterator through columns
$length = 0; //Length of the array
/*
  Print a certain number of radio button type 
*/
if(!empty($words['0']) && $i==1) {
  $length = count($words['0']); //Needed to know how many radio button we have to show
debug($length);
echo('Mot : 1');
//Now things starts to be wrong
?>
<html>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Choose one : </legend>
  <!--
    Print radio button depending on the number of words,
    could be all of them, or only 1.
  -->
</html>
<?php
  if($j < $length) { 
    ?>
    <html>
    <label for="radio-1">$words['0']['0']</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
    </html>
    <?php
    $j++;
  }
  if($j < $length) {
    ?>
    <html>
    <label for="radio-2">$words['0']['1']</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
    </html>
    <?php
    $j++;
  }
  if($j < $length) {
    ?>
    <html>
    <label for="radio-3">$words['0']['2']</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
    </html>
    <?php
    $j++;
  }
  if($j < $length) {
    ?>
    <html>
    <label for="radio-4">$words['0']['3']</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-4">
    </html>
    <?php
    $j++;
  }
  ?>
  <!--... Up to 10 times-->
  </fieldset>
  </html>
<?php
} 
$i++; //Moving to the next row
//Same as above, but on an other row
if(!empty($words['1']) && $i==2) {
  $length = count($words['0']);
  echo('Mot : 2');
  //etc...
```

I know it's monstrous to veteran  but I couldn't find something else.

So, is there a way of printing a various amount of checkboxes properly ?

**ANSWER**

Thanks to the answer of Pol, I managed to do something that's working, it's still a bit disgusting, but it's wayyy better than my original way :

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($newkeywords as $words) {?>
  <h2>Groupe <?php $i?></h2>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>word  '<?php echo($words[0])?>' :</legend>
    <?php foreach ($words as $word) {?>
      <label for=<?php 'checkbox-'.$i ?>><?php echo($word)?></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name=<?php 'checkbox'.$i ?> id=<?php 
'checkbox'.$i ?></br>
      <?php $i=$i+1;?>
      <?php
    }
  $i=1;
  ?></br><?php
}
?>
```

Still eager for other answers, it probably could be done better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure I followed but if you have a variable named 'words' and depending on how many words the length would be different. You can solve this using a foreach.

```
foreach($words as $word) : 
   // here you just print the row
   // because the foreach will go through all words one by one.
   // if you dont know how to access $word you can use var_dump($word) 
   // and then figure it out
   echo '<label for="radio-1">'.$word['0'].'</label>';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">':
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't think of it, I edited the question with a solution of my problem with what you told me :)

Comment: glad it helped you then, you should mark your question as answered then  I guess